# O método MediaPlayer.create() é chamado no background?

Tags: java, android

Estava lendo a documentação do Android Media Playback e me ocorreu uma dúvida. Na documentação falava que não é aconselhável chamar o método `mediaPlayer.prepare()` na *thread* responsável pela UI, e gostaria de saber se o método `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.amostra_de_audio)` é chamado no *background* ou é necessário alguma configuração adicional. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `MediaPlayer.create()` não é assíncrono. Não poderia ser porque ele retorna uma instância de *MediaPlayer*.
Ele internamente chama o método `prepare()` retornando assim o *MediaPlayer* pronto a ser usado.

Para se conseguir o mesmo de forma assíncrona terá de se criar uma instância, através de `new` e chamar o método `prepareAsync()`.

```
MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
....
....
myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }

});
```

O método `onPrepared()` do *OnPreparedListener* passado ao método `setOnPreparedListener()` será chamado quando o *MediaPlayer* estiver pronto para ser usado.