# MediaPlayer não reproduz arquivo de som existente na pasta assets

Tags: java, android

Como faço para executar o som na pasta assets, no Android Studio? Quando o som está na pasta raw executa normal, mas preciso executar na pasta assets, para passar o nome dinamicamente, abaixo está o exemplo, porém ainda não funciona.

```
public void playSom() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Iniciando Som...");
        if (mp01.isPlaying()) {
            mp01.stop();
            mp01.release();
            mp01 = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor assets = getAssets().openFd("errou_1.mp3");
        mp01.setDataSource(assets.getFileDescriptor(), assets.getStartOffset(), assets.getLength());
        //mp01.prepare();
        mp01.prepareAsync();
        mp01.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        //mp01.setLooping(true);
        mp01.start();
        assets.close();

        if (mp01.isPlaying()) {
            System.out.println("Tocando Som ( OK )...");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está em que é feito o *start* antes do *player* estar preparado:

```
mp01.prepareAsync();
mp01.setVolume(1f, 1f);
//mp01.setLooping(true);
mp01.start();
```

O método `prepareAsync()`, sendo assíncrono, retorna de imediato, possibilitando que `mp01.start();` seja executado antes de o player estar preparado.

Use o método síncrono `mp01.prepare();` ou use um [MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105605/2541) para executar o start.

<sub>Nota: Parto do principio que o arquivo `errou_1.mp3` existe e está colocado numa pasta com o nome `assets` dentro da pasta `main`.</sub>

É possível usar aos arquivos existentes na pasta `raw`, através do nome, desta forma:

```
int soundResId = getResources().getIdentifier("errou_1", "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,soundResId);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54233/discussion-on-answer-by-ramaral-mediaplayer-nao-reproduz-arquivo-de-som-existent)